# Function.prototype.apply.apply - why call it twice

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Today while inspecting Jasmine's source code [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L1959) I've stumbled across the following:

```
if (queueableFn.timeout) {
    timeoutId = Function.prototype.apply.apply(self.timeout.setTimeout, [j$.getGlobal(), [function() {
      var error = new Error('Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.');
      onException(error);
      next();
    }, queueableFn.timeout()]]);
}
```

I'm interested in why `apply` is called twice here `prototype.apply.apply`

Comment: ignorance i guess: `Function.prototype.apply.apply == Function.apply` i use `eval.apply` to grab `apply()` (they are all the same) when no-one's looking, like a throw-away console script...

Comment: sorry, didn't understand you, ignorance of whom?

Comment: who ever wrote the code is ignorant of how js works, that's all...

Comment: @Maximus whoever wrote that code wrote the worst code i've seen in a long time

Comment: I think they meant to write `self.timeout.setTimeout.apply(j$.getGlobal(), [
  function() {},
  queueableFn.timeout()
])
`

Comment: It is mainly to get around certain bugs in e.g. IE. Some functions don't have `apply` or a buggy implementation on it.

Comment: @dandavis and, no, they're not the same thing. `var f = function(x,y,z) { return this.a + x + y + z }; Function.prototype.apply.apply(f, [{a:100}, [1, 2, 3]]); //=> 106` Run that with `Function.prototype.apply` instead of `Function.prototype.apply.apply`.

Comment: @naomik: I am the ignorant one i guess (or up too late), fair enough, i didn't look that hard and figured they were trying to do something slightly different than they are. when i grab `eval.apply`, i _do_ end up having to bind/call/apply it, but if I inlined it, it would appear as eval.apply.apply, duh!

Comment: @dandavis no one is calling you ignorant, it's ok ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [commit that introduced this syntax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/commit/61a1f934887ca34fa00000beb4f4c2ab99d2cc53) explains everything:

> Older IE fixes  Still not green, but getting close. Summary of Older
>   IE discrepancies:
>
> - *Older IE doesn't have apply/call on the timing functions*
> - Older IE doesn't allow applying falsy arguments
> - Older IE doesn't allow setting onclick to undefined values
> - Older IE doesn't have text property on dom nodes

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit on how that works? `Function.prototype.apply` returns native apply function, and than when apply is called on it, the `Function.prototype.apply` should be called, not `setTimeout` which is passed as a context

Comment: @Maximus: `apply.apply(fn, [ctx, args])` is essentially equivalent to `fn.apply(ctx, args)`, except for the case that `fn.apply !== apply` (just like this again is equivalent to `ctx.fn(...args)`, except that `ctx.fn` typically is not `fn`).

Comment: I find it hard to understand how _apply.apply(fn, [ctx, args]) is essentially equivalent to fn.apply(ctx, args)_, what do I need to know to understand this?

Comment: @Maximus You know what `apply` does in general, right? Now just disregard that the method we are applying is `apply` itself - it's the same for `call` or other function methods: `x.bind(y,  ...args)` ⇔ `bind.apply(x, [y, ...args])`